# Euclidean distance two pixels, each belonging to different images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to implement Naive Bayes Nearest Neighbor (NBNN) for image classification. In the algorithm it asks for the Euclidean distance between two pixels belonging to different images.

I have 1) a set of m-images in a m-by-40,000 matrix (where 40,000 is the number of pixels in one image) and 2) another set of n-images in a n-by-40,000 matrix.

1) is the training set and 2) is the validation set.

In order for me to apply NBNN, from my understanding, I need to find the Euclidean distance between each pixels of 2) to the corresponding pixels of 1).

My question is, given two grey scale values, one from 1) and the other from 2), how would I find the Euclidean distance between them in order to apply k-NN?

Comment: Just a quick practical question: what would be the expected dimensionality of the output matrix of distances?

Comment: From my understanding of the Naive Bayes Nearest Neighbor, it should be m-by-40,000, given 1-by-40,000 test image and m-by-40,000 training set. From there, I would be looking for the minimum value for each pixel(column) to find the nearest neighbor. Please let me know if I'm understanding this incorrectly.

Comment: @viviboox3, I'm also trying to take this approach with a project in MATLAB. I've gone through Boiman's paper on NBNN but I'm still having a hard time understanding the approach. I thought the whole point of NBNN was to come up with class descriptors and then compute image-to-class distances. Is this what you did here? Also, if you could point me to a good explanation of the algo, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let x, y be two gray-scale 200-by-200 images. Pixels levels are `x1,x2,...x40000` and `y1, y2,...y40000`.
The euclidean distance between x and y is `d(x,y)=sqrt(sum_i((xi-yi)^2))`

Answer (score 0):

I will refer to the notation and definition given at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)

You have 1d-data, thus `p=(p1)` and `q=(q1)`. `e(p,q)=sqrt((p1-q1)^2)=abs(p1-q1)`

For the 1d-case, the euclidean distance is the absolute difference of the grey values.

Comment: So for 1-d images, the location of pixels do not matter? m-by-40,000 matrix I have corresponds to m-images, each 200-by-200 pixels, therefore total pixel = 40,000.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, I answered how to calculate the euclidean distance of colour values. You may also apply the euclidean distance to positions.

Comment: I'm trying to implement knn algorithm on sets of images to classify emotions. If I have a set of images for the training and one image for testing, I need to find the training example that minimizes the distance between each pixels. My images are 200-by-200. Can I still apply the euclidean distance for 1d-case to this? I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear. Thank you for your input.